# CakePHP - FormHelper not outputting form tags

Tags: html, forms, cakephp, form-helpers

I have the following form declaration:

```
<div class="edit-dialog span-10" style="display:none;">
  <div class="edit-message span-10" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
    <span>Editing: <a style="text-decoration:none"></a></span>
  </div>
  <?php
    echo $this->Form->create('Voicenote', array('action' => 'edit'));
    echo $this->Form->input('title', array(
      'div' => false,
      'class' => 'input-text recorder',
      'label' => array(
        'class' => 'inlined',
        'text' => ''
      ),
      'id' => 'VoicenoteEditTitle',
      'placeholder' => 'Title',
      'style' => 'margin-bottom:10px;',
      'onsubmit' => 'return false;'
    ));

    echo $this->Form->input('tags', array(
      'div' => false,
      'class' => 'input-text recorder',
      'id' => 'VoicenoteEditTags',
      'label' => false, 
      'placeholder' => 'Tags',
      'onsubmit' => 'return false;'
    ));
    echo $this->Form->button('Cancel', array(
      'class' => 'button medium blue',
      'id' => 'cancel-edit',
      'style' => 'float:left;margin-top:50px;'
    ));
    echo $this->Form->submit('Save', array(
      'class' => 'button medium blue',
      'id' => 'save-edit',
      'style' => 'float:right;margin-top:50px;'
    ));
  ?> 
  <input type="hidden" id="edit-container-index" value="">
</div>
```

It's not outputting the `<form></form>` tags and I have declared my forms this way throughout my app, adding the `$this->Form->end()` doesn't work either, any clues?

EDIT: explicitly declaring the `<form></form>` tags does not output them either

EDIT 2: there is something really weird I'm noticing. I have 4 forms on the page with the problem, If I remove the rendering of the element with the problem, another one of my forms wont render, the one right after it.

Comment: Is the form helper added to the var $helpers in the controller? Try turning debug on in app/config/core.php

Comment: Yes it is, debug outputs no problems, I declare other forms from elements in the same manner on the same view and In my layout as well, they both work but this one won't

Comment: At this point we really need to see the whole page to determine what's gone wrong. The code you posted behaves correctly when dropped into a fresh template; there's some external factor that's messing up your code.

Comment: I already found the issue, it was another unclosed form in one of my elements, closing the form fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have a submit button. just add end() after submit button in your ctp file.

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->create('users');
echo $this->Form->input('username');
echo $this->Form->input('password');
echo $this->Form->submit('login');
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

Comment: Also tried this doesn't work, like I said even explicitly adding the <form> tags doesn't work

Comment: http://dc388.4shared.com/download/7amUwmr5/tsid20111009-212843-57b8d679/Screenshot-1.png - i copy your code in ctp file and form created. please check your cake source. download last stable version. i hope that been useful for you.

Comment: All other forms on the site are being created correctly in the same manner, whatever it is it's specific to this form

Comment: The problem was another form that didn't have the closing tag.

Comment: I was having the same problem. You were right .. My closing statement began with <?php $this->Form-End() ?> instead of <?= $this->Form->end() ?> .... That's so stupid I know ...

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think if you change last echo to

```
echo $this->Form->end( array(
  'label'=>'Save',
  'class' => 'button medium blue',
  'id' => 'save-edit',
  'style' => 'float:right;margin-top:50px;'
));
```

it should work